# Resize the Jpanel with in Jframe in java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, resizable

I have 2 jpanels in Jframe. when i reduce the frame size then the jpanel size need to reduce should not hide. what ever in the jpanel like textbox or label size also need to reduce. share your view for the problem. how to set the width and height for the jframe as well as the Jpanel.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use LayoutManagers for that purpose. Read all about [LayoutManagers here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. but i designed the and completed my work with free design.so anything else apart from that Guillaume Polet. any other way get the window size calculation.

Comment: @GJay : I really don't think so , as to what you talking about is absolute positioning, which I must say, is bound to remain as is, even if you increase/decrease the size of your `JFrame`, so to get the behaviour you looking for you have to shift towards LayoutManager or else create your own. +1 for the answer, though I have to wait till tomorrow to actually convert my words to reality, my limit is done for today :-)

Comment: *"so anything else apart from that"*  Nothing that will work & is easier.